# What is the best option to split table with 6 billion records?

Tags: sql, partitioning, hana

We have tables on a HANA database that contains 6 billion records. The PK in this table is 5 columns of type varchar(30). We would like to divide this set of 6 billion records into up to 50 million batches, which we could replicate with an external tool. So the task is to divide the set into 50 million batches, so that we refer to each of the batches in the `Where` clause. Example:

`select * from bigTable where partition = 1; -- about 50 million records`

`select * from bigTable where partition = 2; -- about 50 million records`

Is there any function, way in HANA that we can use ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer. To be honest I wrote query in T-SQL which doing what I want finally but do not know If it is possible to rewrite it in HANA:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(HASHBYTES('MD5', PKcol1 + PKcol2 + PKcol3 + PKcol4 + PKcol5), 1, 1)) % 120
    , COUNT(*)
FROM bigTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(HASHBYTES('MD5', PKcol1 + PKcol2 + PKcol3 + PKcol4 + PKcol5), 1, 1)) % 120;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would ORDER BY all primary key fields, you can navigate through all entries with OFFSET and LIMIT as long as reading happens in one session so that the cursor stays stable.